# DraggableViews not displaying drag-handles

Tags: views, 8

I installed the DraggableViews module on Drupal 8. 
On one of my views, I replicated the page that I currently use to display the content that I want. 
I renamed the new page adding "Admin" to the title
Then I follow the instructions I found on various places:

1. Change the Admin block Format section and choose Table.
2. Add the field "Draggableviews: Weight" at the Fields section, place it after the "Content: Title" field.Make sure not to check "Exclude from display". Please note that the instructions mention the "Draggableviews: Content" field but I don't have this option (Is there something wrong here?)
3. Add "DraggableViews: Weight" at the Sort criteria section and place it as the first Sort criteria.
4. Save the view.

then I get a page the list all my items, show the weight of each of the items (0 by default) but I can't change the weight and no drag-handles are shown.

Any help?

Comment: Hey Luke, welcome to Drupal Answers. We love to help you but this issue is really difficult to follow along. What else can we suggest to you as just following the docs? If these don't work for you there are two possibilities: You did something wrong (maybe restart with a new view), or Draggable Views is broken (which would be a bug report and needs to reported on drupal.org – not here). Please retry what you are doing in a fresh Drupal installation, if that still doesn't work, please post a step-by-step bug report on drupal.org.

Comment: May you have a problem with js. Let check tab console in browser.

Comment: I redid it with a brand new view and still the same. So either there is something I don't get about the way it is supposed to be configures (I found it diffucult to find clear instructions and surprisingly there is no README file provided with the module??) or there is something wrong with my environment (I should probably try to use it on a brand new drupal env) or there is a bug but I doubt I would be the first one to notice this popular module which has been around for a while doesn't work properly. I'll try the brand new env and see how it goes.

Comment: And Mrd, no js error shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "draggable" tables in Drupal have a switch that turns the draggable javascript interface off, and allows you to order the items using a less interactive "ordinary" form with fields to enter weight numbers and a submit button.

There is a link, usually at the top right of the table, that says **Hide row weights** if you have the draggable option turned off, and **Show row weights** if you have it on.

Look for that link, it's probable you just have it turned off.

Once you make the switch it will be "remembered" in a cookie so it will apply for all the draggable tables on the site. Maybe you changed it on some other table, Drupal remembered it, and you're simply seeing the non-draggable case in your draggable views.

I guess this brings up to the surface that "Draggable views" isn't quite an accurate name, because it works even without dragging. Maybe it should be called "Order views" or something similar, but javascript tools usually win that race and this example illustrates it.

I hope this is the issue here. Nothing broken, just a temporary UI blindspot, we've all been there :)

Comment: Thanks prkos. 
Yes I know about this switch, I've used it in the view filter rearrange screen for example. But I have not such switch when I use DraggableViews. And I guess the weight would be editable if the switch was off?

Comment: Can you check whether the link is there in the source? Maybe it's just hidden because of theme layout? Or try turning javascript off (it's easy through Development tools in your browser). But yes you should be able to change the numbers in the Weight column and save the order that way (larger numbers sink to the bottom, negatives float to the top). Do you see the button to save the order?

Comment: Yes there was a CSS issue the hid the handles. All sorted out now, many thanks prkos!

Comment: I'm glad to help! Accept the answer if it solved it for ya :)